# SQL Pivot with missing unique identifier

Tags: sql, sql-server

Update*: ID can be numeric but also alpha-numeric.

I have a Table:

| Index | ID | Allergen | Contains |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | AB | Yes |
| 2 |  | AC | Yes |
| 3 |  | AD | No |
| 4 | 2 | AB | Yes |
| 5 |  | AC | No |
| 6 |  | AD | Yes |
| 7 |  | AE | No |
| 8 |  | AF | Yes |
| 9 | XD123 | AB | No |
| 10 |  | AC | Yes |
| 11 |  | AD | No |
| 12 |  | AE | Yes |
| 13 |  | AF | Yes |

I want to transform/transpose it to look like the below table. Where Yes = the Allergen exists for each of the unique allergen (Where Contains = Yes) and No = Allergen is either null/does not exist for that ID or Contains = No. How would I do that given that the ID only exist for the first row? For example, row 2-3 should also have ID = 1 but it doesn't come with the data.

| ID | AB | AC | AD | AE | AF |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Yes | Yes | No | No | No |
| 2 | Yes | No | Yes | No | Yes |
| 3 | No | Yes | No | Yes | Yes |

Edit/additional: Even if I can populate the blank IDs with the previous pre-populated ID it will be very helpful:

| ID | Allergen | Contains |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AB | Yes |
| 1 | AC | Yes |
| 1 | AD | No |
| 2 | AB | Yes |
| 2 | AC | No |
| 2 | AD | Yes |
| 2 | AE | No |
| 2 | AF | Yes |
| 3 | AB | No |
| 3 | AC | Yes |
| 3 | AD | No |
| 3 | AE | Yes |
| 3 | AF | Yes |

Comment: How do you know that those `AC`'s aren't all related to ID `1` when they have no value in the `ID` column?

Comment: The data comes in this format, it is sort of like a hierarchy where ID 1 have AB AC AD under it. Basically the blank ID need to inherit the ID from the ID in the previous populated row.

Comment: If you do not have a column to order by the there is no guarantee that the columns will be in the same order from one time that you query to another.

Comment: Is there a way to populate the missing ID similar to the 3rd table I added? @Kendle

Comment: I can also add an Index column in addition to the ID

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution to populate the id column if there is another column which can be used to determine order.
We then proceed to pivot using `COALESCE` to replace **null** values with **No**

> ```
> create table aTable(
>   index_  int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
>   ID int, Allergen char(2),   Contains_ char(3));
> insert into aTable values
> (1,'AB','Yes'),
> (null,'AC','Yes'),
> (null,'AD','No'),
> (2,'AB','Yes'),
> (null,'AC','No'),
> (null,'AD','Yes'),
> (null,'AE','No'),
> (null,'AF','Yes'),
> (3,'AB','No'),
> (null,'AC','Yes'),
> (null,'AD','No'),
> (null,'AE','Yes'),
> (null,'AF','Yes');
> ```

> ```
> update aTable 
> set ID = (select max(ID) from aTable a where a.index_ <= aTable.index_ );
> ```

> ```
> select * from aTable;
> ```

> ```
> index_ | ID | Allergen | Contains_
> -----: | -: | :------- | :--------
>      1 |  1 | AB       | Yes      
>      2 |  1 | AC       | Yes      
>      3 |  1 | AD       | No       
>      4 |  2 | AB       | Yes      
>      5 |  2 | AC       | No       
>      6 |  2 | AD       | Yes      
>      7 |  2 | AE       | No       
>      8 |  2 | AF       | Yes      
>      9 |  3 | AB       | No       
>     10 |  3 | AC       | Yes      
>     11 |  3 | AD       | No       
>     12 |  3 | AE       | Yes      
>     13 |  3 | AF       | Yes
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>   id,
>   max(coalesce(AB,'No')) AB,
>   max(coalesce(AC,'No')) AC,
>   max(coalesce(AD,'No')) AD,
>   max(coalesce(AE,'No')) AE,
>   max(coalesce(AF,'No')) AF
> FROM   
> (
>     SELECT 
>         *
>     FROM 
>         aTable
> ) t 
> PIVOT(
>     MAX(Contains_) 
>     FOR Allergen IN (
>         [AB], 
>         [AC], 
>         [AD], 
>         [AE], 
>         [AF])
> ) AS pivot_table
> GROUP BY id;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> id | AB  | AC  | AD  | AE  | AF 
> -: | :-- | :-- | :-- | :-- | :--
>  1 | Yes | Yes | No  | No  | No 
>  2 | Yes | No  | Yes | No  | Yes
>  3 | No  | Yes | No  | Yes | Yes
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4f4704d1507a2eedbb74d399caa40c0b)*

Comment: Thank you @Kendle. While updating the ID in the table a lot of the ID were overwritten by the previous ID. I should have about 2000 unique IDs however after updating I'm left with about 10. I think this is because my ID have a combination of numbers and alphanumeric (i.e. some ID are starting with text like OB123) - in this case we can't use Max()?

Comment: It's because the table doesn't have any specific order if we don't specify an order by column. An id with text can be sorted by max(). The difference is that in a alphabet sort 10 comes before 9 because 1 comes before 9.

Comment: Is there anyway to address this having the numberic + alphanumeric combination?